# Access token url and Authorize URL

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, drupal

I am trying to get a Facebook feed from a page for a website (setup using Drupal), and I'm trying to setup OAuth2 authentication.

I've set up the Facebook app, and gotten the app key and app secret - but now the module is asking for "access token url" and "authorize url"

What are these precisely? Do I get them from Facebook, do I generate them myself? Do I need to use code to do it?

I'm reading as much as I can, and I can't even tell if this is a code question or not.

Answer (score 0):

1. App key: ID for your app
2. App secret: Used to get "app access_token"

When the module asks for access_token, it means the access_token of a user/app who has permissions to view current page. Not sure what "authorize_url" means.

What is access_token?

- a random string that identifies a User, App or Page session and provides temporary, secure access to Facebook APIs. (more)[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/]

Do you generate them manually or use code to do it?

- When a user connects her/his facebook account with your app, facebook returns an **user access_token**
- To get **app access_token** you will have to use the *app_key* and *app_secret*. A sample code:
  `GET /oauth/access_token?
   client_id={app-id}
  &client_secret={app-secret}
  &grant_type=client_credentials`

On a sidenote I implore you to try out [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and build your queries there before writing      queries in your app.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate these yourself, typically by writing code. There's a number of ways of simplifying this process though, once of which is by using Temboo.

Temboo makes it easy to work with APIs, and that means simplifying the OAuth process. You can use the Temboo's OAuth Wizards to generate a Facebook access token without writing any code. You can also move beyond the Wizards to generate both tokens and authorization URLs using code that Temboo will automatically generate for you in the language of your choice, including PHP.

Check out the videos here to learn more about how Temboo can help with OAuth:

https://www.temboo.com/videos

(Full disclosure: I work for Temboo, so please let me know if you have any questions!)